# onPress works only on second press

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project with 2 files:

**App.js**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import GoalInput from "./components/GoalInput";

export default function App() {
  const [goalsList, setGoalsList] = useState([]);
  const addGoalHandler = (goal) => {
    setGoalsList([...goalsList, { text: goal, id: Math.random().toString() }]);
  };
  const deleteItem = (itemId) => {
    setGoalsList(goalsList.filter((goal) => goal.id !== itemId));
  };

  //console.log(goalsList);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <GoalInput onAddGoal={addGoalHandler} />
      <View style={styles.goalsContainer}>
        <FlatList
          alwaysBounceVertical={false}
          data={goalsList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            return item.id;
          }}
          renderItem={(itemData) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteItem(itemData.item.id)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 40,
                    backgroundColor: "purple",
                    color: "white",
                    margin: 10,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  {itemData.item.text}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
  goalsContainer: {
    flex: 3,
  },
});
```

**GoalInput.js**:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const GoalInput = ({ onAddGoal }) => {
  const [goal, setGoal] = useState("");

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholder="Your Goal"
        value={goal}
        onChangeText={(goalText) => {
          setGoal(goalText);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Send"
        onPress={() => {
          onAddGoal(goal);
          setGoal("");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderBottomColor: "gray",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginBottom: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderColor: "gray",
    width: "80%",
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default GoalInput;
```

Whenever I add an item, and then press on an item in the list to delete it, the first press is not recognized (I know because I put a `console.log` inside the `deleteItem` function and nothing is logged. Only the second time is recognized, and then every other item is deleted on the first press.

And then again, if I enter a new item, the strange behavior repeats itself.